# Is there any problems with naming a local variable `property`?

Tags: c++, clion

I'm trying to refactor a local variable in CLion to name it `property` but it won't actually let me. There's no error when I do it myself but the refactoring tool is a bit less tedious.

Renaming `property__` to `property`

[image: Renaming property__ to property]

Is this a bug from CLion or there's actually a reason it doesn't want me to do that ? I imagine that if it's not a bug, it might be entering in conflict with something else making it safer for me to use another name.

PS: To curious wondering I need to call a variable something as generic as `property`, I'm looping through XML attributes and the XML library I'm using call that properties (I'm not sure why).

```
for(c_xml_config::nodeProperty property : xmlModule.properties)
{
    //Lots of this calling this variable making it tedious to rename at hand...
}
```

Comment: Du you have any `using namespace` directives in your code?

Comment: @NeilButterworth No, I don't

Comment: Identifiers containing double underscores are reserved.

Comment: @AndreiAndrey I just needed an example for the screenshot.

Comment: Remember for future not to use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In plain C++ `property` is not reserved, so yes you can use it.

It appears to be a keyword in a [Microsoft C++ extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/property-cpp).